# variable scope issue (nodejs/javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

If the variable **value** is global why do i get undefined when i *console.log()* it out of socket.on('Led_1')?
`

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var value;
var socket = io.connect('http://105.155.150.85/');

socket.on('Led_1',function(data){
    value = data.message;
    console.log(value); // Here it shows the value.
});

console.log(value); // here it shows undefined.
```

`

Comment: Because the last `console.log(value); // here it shows undefined.` will run before the `socket.on()`, hence not yet assigned anything

Comment: Thanks for your response, so how can make this work?

Comment: Follow the guidelines at the dupe link

Comment: the think that i want to understand is what would happen if i call an Asynchronous function inside of a Synchronous like this:displayState_RGB(){
        socket.on('Led_RGB',function(data){
          val = data.message;
          console.log('RGB: '+val);
        //Le Cercle s'affiche avec la couleur de la LED RGB.
        return(<Icon reverse type='ionicon' color={val}/>);
        });
      }

Comment: Simply put, an async method will generally allow the code to continue (non-blocking) on the next line, and the async mehtod will return when it's done, and if one depend on a returned value that that async method will return, one will get an error as you did here.